# How my django model field can take value from a function defined in default

Tags: django, django-models

Having this model:

```
class Settings(models.Model):

    INT = "int"
    FLOAT = "float"
    STRING = "string"
    JSON = "json"
    BOOLEAN = "boolean"
    VALUE_TYPES = (
        (INT , "int"),
        (FLOAT , "float"),
        (STRING , "string"),
        (JSON , "json"),
        (BOOLEAN , "boolean"),
    )

    def casted_value(self):
        if self.value_type == Settings.INT:
            return int(self.value)
        elif self.value_type == Settings.FLOAT:
            return float(self.value)
        elif self.value_type == Settings.STRING:
            return str(self.value)
        elif self.value_type == Settings.BOOLEAN:
            return bool(self.value)
        elif self.value_type == Settings.JSON:
            return json.dumps(self.value_type)



    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    value_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=VALUE_TYPES, default=casted_value)
```

I am trying to give to my `value_type` field value based on the function `casted_value`.
The concept is to return the value based on the type.

When I am trying to migrate I come up with the error :

**TypeError: casted_value() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

How is the right way to define my `casted_value` function in order the `value_type` field to take the value from this function?

Comment: I don't think this will work. `default` will only kick in if you set `value_type` to `None`, so `value_type`'s default handler (`casted_value`) depending on a value that is set on itself does not make sense.

Comment: @bdbd ok, how can i handle it to end up to a solution in my case. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: Maybe override `save` and do the processing there?